# Return result from Ternary in one line (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, shorthand, ternary

In JavaScript, rather than having to assign the result to a variable, is it possible to `return` the result of a ternary in one line of code?

e.g. Instead of this:

```
function getColor(val){
    var result = val <= 20 ? '#000' : val >= 80 ? '#999' : '#555';
    return result;
}
```

Can we do something like this...

```
function getColor(val){
    return val <= 20 ? '#000' : val >= 80 ? '#999' : '#555';
}
```

I am asking this because I just tried the above and nothing was returned.

Comment: OK I realise that was a very bad example now. Of course you could just say return A > B. Let me edit.

Comment: If you're going to use `true` and `false` make sure all the letters are lower-case. Not `True` and `False`.

Comment: Sorry it was literally the quickest example I could think of. I will remember for next time.

Comment: Your function is correct and worked for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Oh then the issue must lie elsewhere in my code. Sorry for wasting time. At least I know that it is possible now!

Comment: possibly value of function argument `val` is string, check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's possible.  Also you can make your code even more compact.

```
function isAGreaterThanB(){
    return a > b;
}
```

Above code will return `true` if `a` is greater, `false` if not.

Answer (score 0):

You can just return whatever `a > b` evaluates to.

```
 function isAGreaterThanB(){
     return a > b;
 }
```

As `a > b` evaluates to either True or False, you can just return that value directly.

Actually doing it how you typed is, is a really bad way to do it and is unneccessarily complicated for something as basic as this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you could for example say this:

```
function getBiggerNumber(a, b){
    return a > b ? a : b
}
```

this function returns `a` if `a` is bigger than `b` and `b` if `b` is bigger than `a`.
Just for completeness: It would also return `b` if `a` and `b` would be equal